# Searching for index of array from arraylist

Tags: java

I want to find a index of an array in array list such that,

```
String[]names=new String[x];
new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(names));
int w=......indexOf(search);
```

I don't know what am I going to suppose to write on ......

Comment: What specifically do you want the matching criteria to be? If it's `a==b`, then just use `List.indexOf`

Comment: `names` is filled with `null`. Unless `search == null`, you won't find it in there.

Comment: i just want to find the array index that i am searching for

Comment: @MuhammedTuğrul That's exactly my question. What are you searching for?

Comment: Ben de diyorum ki onun ne onemi var sadece aradığım kelimenin index ini istiyorum EDIT= Sorry for turkish i explained him to what i just want and dont want

Comment: Örnek kod üzerinden senin anlaman da bizim anlatmamız da rahat oluyor boşuna istenmiyor ama ben cevaplayayım.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `List` interface has the [`indexOf` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf-java.lang.Object-):

> Returns the index of the first occurrence of the specified element in this list, or -1 if this list does not contain the element

So, you just need to invoke this method.

Note that

```
new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(names));
```

creates a `List` (two `List`s, actually), but doesn't actually store the created list anywhere; so you don't end up with anything you can invoke the method on.

Either:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(names));
int w = list.indexOf(search);
```

or:

```
int w = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(names)).indexOf(search);
```

or, even easier, since `Arrays.asList` returns a `List`, and you don't need to mutate the list to search it:

```
int w = Arrays.asList(names).indexOf(search);
```

Comment: Thank you, that is it what i am looking for